# How to show unique name of every points in highCharts using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am new to angular and developing a project using it. I need to show a scatter graph by using HighChart and in that need to show a unique name in a tooltip of every point, Names and points come from API.

```
    plotOptions:{
        scatter:{
          dataLables:{
            enabled: true
          }, 
           marker:{
              enabled:true
           },
           tooltip: {
              borderRadius:20,
              shared:true 
           }
        }
     },
     series : [{
       name:"Forecast",
       color:'blue',
       data:data:[{"name":"firstTest" ,"x":4.2,"y":1.3}]
    },{
       name:"Threshold",
       color:'orange',
       data:[{"name":"secondTest" ,"x":3.2,"y":5.3}]
    }]
  };
```

Comment: Hi @Shivank, What is the exact problem? Your chart options works correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4axmue8w/

Comment: Hi, The problem is the tooltip shows the series name but not the point name like I want the tooltip to show "secondTest" also but it is showing only "Threshold".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `tooltip.pointFormat` property to add the point's name to a tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.name} {point.y}</b><br/>'
},
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gh3yd2q0/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat